# Does this AWS S3 bucket strategy make sense?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

I'm still new to S3 and am trying to get a handle on how to use buckets to organize authorization groups in my app.

My app requires the following functionality:

1. Every user belongs to a workspace
2. Users can have private items that only they can access
3. Users can share items with everyone in their workspace
4. Users can share items with other workspaces
5. Users can publish public items that anyone on the web can see

Here's my attempt at translating that to S3:

```
my_app
 ┣ workspace_a
 ┣ workspace_b
 ┣ public
 ┣ user_a
 ┣ user_b
 ┣ ...all other users and workspaces (could be thousands)
```

There could be tens of thousands of users and workspaces. My initial thought was that this seemed like overkill/abuse of AWS buckets, but I don't see any pricing related to number of buckets on the [S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/#:%7E:text=*%20S3%20Intelligent%2DTiering%20standard%20and,and%20Deep%20Archive%20access%20tiers.&text=minimum%20storage%20duration.-,Objects%20stored%20longer%20than%20the%20minimum%20storage%20duration,incur%20a%20minimum%20request%20charge.).

Is this a scaleable way to use S3 buckets? If not, how would you handle this?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Okay. Due to a soft limit of around 100 buckets, the above solution clearly isn't the right approach for thinking about access control in S3.

I think it makes more sense to use IAM (AWS Identity and Access Management) to manage my users and groups, then control access to specific resources that way.

I'll dig in to this more and update if I figure it out.

Comment: Are you proposing to create thousands of S3 buckets? That's probably an anti-pattern and there is a soft limit of 100 buckets in your account, which can be raised.

Comment: @Maurice well that's certainly good to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you genuinely need the level of granularity that you've advertised for 10k+ users and workspaces then, in my opinion, you almost certainly **cannot** solve this using IAM users and IAM policies. You will run into [IAM user limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html#reference_iam-quotas-entities) (5000 users) and [size limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html#reference_iam-quotas-entity-length) on S3/IAM policies.

The general solution for providing AWS credentials to 1000s of individual users is to group users into IAM Groups, then provide identity federation (SSO) for those users to assume IAM roles and retrieve STS credentials. But you will still run into policy constraints (or mass file duplication in S3), I think, unless you can simplify the requirements.

You might consider a generic policy-based authorization engine such as [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/).

Comment: that's super helpful. Thanks! I'm using identity federation, so that makes sense. I guess I still have a lot to learn about this ecosystem. Can you explain more about how I'd still run into policy constraints and file duplication? What aspects of my requirements could be simplified in order to prevent that? Thanks for the time and patience 

Answer (score 0):

I'd go so far as to say that you SHOULD NOT solve this by IAM users and IAM policies. If you have thousands of users, consider using an identity provider that's made for the number of users of this scale, such as an external IdP (Okta, Ping, etc) or [AWS SSO](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-and-manage-users-within-aws-sso/). When you have thousands of users, managing that in IAM is not easy. And if your solution is meant for a customer-facing application, you'd want to consider a [customer IAM solution](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-ciam/) (Auth0, Cognito, etc) instead.